# how to control the behaviour of lintr in visual studio code?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Switching from Rstudio to vscode. Biggest problem right now: the linters are constantly bothering me! Take the snippet as an example: [image]
object_name_linter is trying to make me name my variable as `group_markers`instead of `group.markers`. However, in the R community, it's rather common to see `.` within variable names. I couldn't figure out a good way to turn off this linter.

Comment: Linters can be configured using a `.lintr` file: https://github.com/jimhester/lintr/blob/master/README.md#lintr-file-example

Comment: I like VS Code but I love [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com), so I'm switching back from VS Code to RStudio.  The key is to use package [reticulate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/index.html).  
Using dots in variable names is a very bad idea since it can be interpreted by the language as part of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To turn off this specific linter globally, create a config file `~/.lintr`

```
linters: with_defaults(
    object_name_linter = NULL
  )
```

A list of linters: https://lintr.r-lib.org/reference/linters.html

For example, to also disable the linter for maximum line length = 80, the config file `~/.lintr` should be:

```
linters: with_defaults(
    object_name_linter = NULL,
    line_length_linter = NULL
  )
```

Comment: You can also put this in the root of your project or in the directory, should you wish to share your defaults with teammates who will also be editing your code.

Comment: Can anyone suggest where ~/.lintr is supposed to be saved for those of us on Windows?

Comment: @ElliottCollins Usually `C:\Users\username\`

Comment: The first line should be `linters: linters_with_defaults(`.

Answer (score 3):

@danlooo's pointer is probably the proper way to achieve what you are after. I haven't tried it though.

I have very limited experience with linting, and was like you very annoyed by all the squiggly lines and suggestions. It seems linting is something that the `vscode-R` extension comes with out-of-the box.

I found that adding the following line to VSCode's `settings.json` completely disabled linting for R:

```
"r.lsp.diagnostics": false
```

It's also possible to simply uncheck the corresponding box in the VSCode GUI settings for the same effect.