# How to turn off suggestions of lintr

Tags: r, vscode-extensions

I'm using VSCode for R and installed 'R Extension' to use it.
Diagnostics it offers are really helpful, but I don't want to see any suggestions from lintr.

```
posterior_statistic <- c('mean' = 3/(3+14))
3.x <- c(1,2,3)
```

This is a part of my code and lintr gives me the following suggestions that do not affect the code at all.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5spp.png)
What I only want to get is an error code like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po4s1.png)

I could achieve turning off suggestions by modifying '.lintr' file, but it only affects R files in the working directory. I want to turn off such suggestions at default. Help me guys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to control the behaviour of lintr in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443818/how-to-control-the-behaviour-of-lintr-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I should've searched more! Thanks for ur help!